# django admin access rights: edit_user vs. assign access rights

Tags: django, django-admin

In Django Admin: If you add the access right to "edit users" to a user this user can:

- edit any user's profile
- edit all access rights of the user (thus making this user de-facto a superuser)

Is there a way to limit a user to only update another users personal information: email, first_name, last_name, etc?

Comment: Take a look at this https://stackoverflow.com/a/2616201/7470786

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to limit fields in django-admin depending on user?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2615141/how-to-limit-fields-in-django-admin-depending-on-user)